# How do I pass a regex parameter to a preg replace callback in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, parameters, preg-replace-callback

I am using preg_replace_callback to parse my [quote id=123][/quote] bulletin board code tag.  What is the correct way to pass the quote id with a regex parameter?

```
$str = '[quote id=123]This is a quote tag[/quote]';

$str = preg_replace_callback("^[quote id=([0-9]+)](.*?)[/quote]^", _parse_quote("123", "message"), $str);

function _parse_quote($message_id, $original_message){

    $str = '<blockquote>'.$original_message.'</blockquote>';

    return $str;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression should be fixed.

- `[` and `]` should be escaped to match them literally. (`[`, `]` have special meaning in regular expression).

The code is calling `_parse_quote` instead of passing the function to the `preg_replace_callback`. Just pass the function name as string.

You can access the captured group by indexing. (`$matches[2]` to get the second captured group)

```
$str = '[quote id=123]This is a quote tag[/quote]';
$str = preg_replace_callback("^\[quote id=([0-9]+)\](.*?)\[/quote\]^", "_parse_quote",  $str);
echo $str;

function _parse_quote($matches) {
    $str = '<blockquote>' . $matches[2] . '</blockquote>';
    return $str;
}
```

output:

```
<blockquote>This is a quote tag</blockquote>
```